# u-substitution integral $\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate$$\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}dx$$ 
>   using $u$ substituion

My main problem is what to use as my $u$. This is a question given by a professor in a class I am TAing for. Specifically, I do not want this to use trigonometric substitution or integration by parts as these were not covered yet.

Comment: u=x^2 and use sub method

Comment: @Jam that gets me to a problem that is easy to do using integration by parts. Unfortunately, this was not covered yet.

Comment: @PVAL I am not sure what you mean by "easy to do using integration by parts". The answer is the exponential integral, which doesn't seem like something people who don't know integration would be familiar with.

Comment: What level is this calculus course?  The result is not of the sort discussed in second semester (the anti-derivative is not formed from elementary functions).  [If it was proposed to use a standard "technique of integration", I suspect the proposer didn't actually try carrying it out...]

Comment: I don't think the anti derivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Are you sure about this problem?

Comment: @imranfat if you take $u = x^2$, yes. please look more carefully next time.

Comment: I still don't see it. How can the anti derivative be expressed in terms of elementary functions? Wolfram can't do it, and the answer below from Hmedan doesn't look elementary either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}dx=\frac14\int e^{-u}u^{-1}du$$

$$R.H.S=\frac14\int e^{-u}u^{-1}du=\frac14\int_{0}^{u}e^{-u}u^{-1}du+c$$

$$\frac14\int_{0}^{u}e^{-u}u^{-1}du+c=\frac14(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1}du-\int_{u}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1}du)+c=-\frac14 \Gamma(0,u)+d$$

so: $$\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}dx=-\frac14 \Gamma(0,x^2)+d$$

where $c,d$ are arbitrary constants